# Comparator: What is appropriate for comparing ranges of about 50-100 mVs? Can I use an LM741 op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

I am attempting to create a high voltage signal when the voltage from a sensor I am using drops below a certain threshold, which will be between .05 and .1 Volts. I was trying to use an LM741 op amp to do this, but I could not get it to work as a comparator for these small voltages.  Can anyone recommend a component or suggest a way to get an LM741 to work for comparing such small voltages?[image]

Comment: Input offset is going to start to play a role in your accuracy when you're dealing with signals in the millivolts. Source a low-offset comparator and stay away from the 1960s tech (the original 741 debuted in 1968, IIRC)

Comment: @Madmanguruman thank you, I ordered some comparators hopefully they get the job done

Answer (score 1):

The allowable input voltage range for a 741 is 2 volts inside the power rails. This means that on a +/-15V supply, the inputs will still adequately function from -13V to +13V.

If you are trying to tempt performance from a 741 with a grounded negative rail then don't expect the inputs to function lower than 2V above ground and worst case 3V.

[image]

Let's look at a few other things too.

- Input offset voltage maximum of 6 mV
- Input offset voltage drift with temperature 15 uV / degC
- Input resistance - maybe as low as 300kohm
- Input offset current up to 500 nA
- Output voltage swing (from a +/-20V supply) limited to +/-16V

My advice is this - don't use it - pick a better device - even the LM324's inputs encompass the neg rail. My general purpose work-horse op-amp is the AD8605 because it's not at all like the 741 and comes in single, dual and quad packages.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I had some 741s available so I was trying to make it work, and I was overwhelmed by the ordering options when it didn't.  I appreciate the recommendations it is great to know

Comment: Maybe try an LM324 if you've got one -it's inputs go to -Vs. Ditto LF358